# Paypal verify payments

Tags: android

I'm working on paypal android app

payment with android app done and i'm getting response

{
                                                                      "client": {
                                                                          "environment": "sandbox",
                                                                          "paypal_sdk_version": "2.15.3",
                                                                          "platform": "Android",
                                                                          "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
                                                                      },
                                                                      "response": {
                                                                          "create_time": "2017-03-31T09:44:18Z",
                                                                          "id": "PAY-78059841KU835582ULDPCJ2Y",
                                                                          "intent": "sale",
                                                                          "state": "approved"
                                                                      },
                                                                      "response_type": "payment"
                                                                  }

But now I want to verify payment with following rest API

But it's not working

https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI

Everything according to paypal i'm track https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

Comment: "it's not working" is not very descriptive, please explain what exactly goes wrong and what you're expecting.

Comment: I have made a payment with paypal Andoird SDK and now i want to verify it with KEY **PAY-78059841KU835582ULDPCJ2Y** by using rest API **https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI** of paypal that's explain here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/ . But it's not working for me